# Which version of php support both magento 2.2.6 and magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, magento-upgrade

I want to upgrade `Magento 2.2.6`. During the upgrade,it shows php version error. If i upgrade it then it does not support to 2.2.6. kindly suggest the version which will support both.

Answer (score 0):

I you check system requiement for both magento 2.2 and 2.3, PHP ~7.1 will work for both.

You can check for magento 2.3 : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

You can check for magento 2.2 : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: But my current version is PHP Version 7.1.27-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 but it create a problem to execute magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP Version 7.2.19 and ubuntu0.18.04.1 i can able to install both 2.2 and 2.3

Answer (score 0):

For `Magento 2.2.6`:

Supported PHP versions:

~7.0.13

~7.1.0

For `Magento 2.3`:

Supported PHP versions:

~7.1.3

~7.2.0